# Android ListView not displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working at a messaging application and I have followed a tutorial until a certain point when it didn't work anymore.
I used firebase and I have a problem. The program doesn't display my listview and I cannot see the messages I sent.

I would appreciate any kind of suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

**MainActivity**

```
private void displayChatMessage()

   {

       ListView listOfMessage = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
       //Retrieve Chats
       Query query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");

        //FireBaseListOptions constructor
        FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new 
        FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setQuery(query,ChatMessage.class)
                .setLayout(R.layout.activity_main)
                .build();


        /*FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                    .setQuery(query,ChatMessage.class)
                    .build();
                    */

        //Pass to constructor

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position)
            {
                //Get references to the views of list_item.xml
                TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;
                messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);


                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",model.getMessageTime()));


            }
        };
        listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"



        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Message..."
            android:id="@+id/input"

            /></android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_message"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fab"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: maybe your query returns no elements, doesn't it?

Comment: Have start listening for changes?